# Failed to load module an installed module in Intern/Leadfoot

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, intern, leadfoot

### Meta -

OS:  Ubuntu 14.

Selenium Version: 2.53

Browser:  Chrome.
Browser Version:  51.0.2704.103 (64-bit)

### Expected Behavior -

The selenium-driver is imported.

### Actual Behavior -

The selenium-driver is not imported.

```
Got following parameters:
seleniumserver.port: 4444
chrome.driver.path: selenium/chromedriver/linux64/chromedriver
kibi.url: http://192.168.50.10
kibi.shield.password: undefined
kibi.shield.username: undefined
Running "intern:community" (intern) task
Error: Failed to load module node_modules/selenium-webdriver from /home/trex/Development/Siren/kibi-integration/node_modules/selenium-webdriver.js (parent: tests/functional/support/page/Datasource)
  at ReadFileContext.callback  <node_modules/intern/node_modules/dojo/loader.ts:831:119>
  at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterOpen [as oncomplete]  <fs.js:303:13>
Warning: Test failure; check output above for details. Use --force to continue.
```

### Steps to reproduce -

I use [Intern](https://theintern.github.io/intern/#what-is-intern) to write a test. 
A piece of my code. 
`cat tests/functional/community/index.js`

```
/*global define*/
define([
  'intern!object',
  'intern/chai!assert',
  'require',
  '../support/page/EnhSearchTable',
  '../support/page/KibiDashboard',
  '../support/page/Datasource'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require, EnhSearchTable, KibiDashboard, Datasource) {
  var intern = require('intern');
  var args = intern.args;
  var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
  var driver = new webdriver.Builder().build();
...
...
...
});
```

The content of selenium-driver in node_modules:

```
tree -L 1 /home/trex/Development/Siren/kibi-integration/node_modules/sel
enium-webdriver/
/home/trex/Development/Siren/kibi-integration/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/
├── builder.js
├── CHANGES.md
├── chrome.js
├── edge.js
├── error.js
├── example
├── executors.js
├── firefox
├── http
├── ie.js
├── index.js
├── io
├── lib
├── LICENSE
├── net
├── node_modules
├── NOTICE
├── opera.js
├── package.json
├── phantomjs.js
├── proxy.js
├── README.md
├── remote
├── safari.js
├── test
└── testing
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To load a Node module in an AMD test, you'll need to use the `intern/dojo/node` loader plugin. Try:

`var webdriver = require('intern/dojo/node!selenium-webdriver')`